# Download ExtremeXOS

Tags: switch, network, extreme

I need to update the extreme switch, I found a lot of instructions but I don't know where to download the latest version of extremeXOS. Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: What's wrong with https://www.extremenetworks.com/ ?

Comment: At first glance, everything is fine and the first thing I did was visit this resource. But due to my inattention, apparently, or some other factors, I could not find the download page there. If it is not difficult for you to specify more precisely in which section I can select the available hardware and download the software for it. In my case, it's an x440-g2.
Thank you again.

Comment: Try *Support -> Support Portal -> Downloads*.